# template and decltype for void f(int)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, traits, decltype

I am learning writing my own traits using C++11 borrowing only `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`.

I've created the following trait:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
struct is_farg1: std::false_type {};

template <typename R, typename A>
struct is_farg1<R (*)(A)> : std::true_type {};
```

Now consider a program including the above trait, and the following code:

```
void f(int) {}

int main() {
    std::cout << "is_farg1<decltype(f)>  : " << is_farg1<decltype(f)>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "is_farg1<void(*)(int)> : " << is_farg1<void(*)(int)>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
is_farg1<decltype(f)>  : 0
is_farg1<void(*)(int)> : 1
```

My questions:

1. Why `is_farg1<void(*)(int)>::value` is `true` while `is_farg1<decltype(f)>::value` returned `false`?
2. If my trait is incorrectly written then how can I check if the given function has one and only one argument so I could use also `decltype(f)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Becasue `decltype(f)` gives the exact function type (i.e. `void(int)`) but not the function pointer type (i.e. `void(*)(int)`). When [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) is used for entity,

> If the argument is an unparenthesized [id-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) or an unparenthesized [class member access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) expression, then `decltype` yields the type of the *entity* named by this expression.

You can add another specialization for the function type like

```
template <typename R, typename A>
struct is_farg1<R (A)> : std::true_type {};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jpnk8tykF6eWTrbu)

Or check the type as function pointer like

```
is_farg1<decltype(f)*>::value
//                  ^

// or
is_farg1<decltype(&f)>::value
//                ^
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XsyVm41WSbZONWqn)

Comment: @Grzegorz It would be a reference to function type, i.e. `void(&)(int)`. `(f)` is considered as expression (instead of entity).

Comment: Thank you. I am surprised that `decltype(f)` would return `R (A)`. Is this even correct? Like `void (int)` ? If I declare `decltype(f) g` the how would compiler know that `g` is a function. This is more a trick to me ;) Thank you again!

Comment: @Grzegorz Yes, `void(int)` is a function type which takes an `int` and returns nothing. You can write `decltype(f) g;` which declares a function named `g`, just same as `void g(int);`. [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hvryHk8RcF661xAW)

Comment: Great! Thank you.